# APK not able to upload on google play store

Tags: android, android-studio

Warnings

Check these warnings before starting the rollout of this release. Addressing the warnings on this page will ensure your existing users are able to upgrade to the latest version of your app.

How i can fix that in android studio?

Unoptimized APK

Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with that.  Its telling you that you have assets for multiple screen sizes being sent to users, and that they'll only use one of them.  You can make your apk smaller by building and uploading multiple apks, but unless you have a very large apk its probably not worth the time/effort.

If you're not able to upload it at all, you're missing another error somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks For your replying you mean right now my APK file size is so big I need to decrease it? Right now File Size is 3.90MB

Comment: No, its bigger than it needs to be, but its not the actual problem.  This is an informational warning, not a blocking error.  If you have one of those, its elsewhere and unrelated to this warning.